# How to remove the migration in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-migrations, sqlite3-ruby

I have been trying to use devise to make an authentication system for a blog that I am programming.When I try to view the blog, it says (Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.),  and when I run the command, it fails and renders this message:

```
Moussas-MacBook-Pro:theBlog moussasarr$ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20141031151735 SorceryCore: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:authors)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "authors" already exists: CREATE TABLE "authors" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "username" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "crypted_password" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "salt" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /Users/moussasarr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

. I did migrate the authors table in the past but I had to restart from an earlier point as it was not working out. How can I delete the SorceryCore  migration to make a new one ?

Here is the migration table:

```
class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     create_table :authors do |t|
      t.string :username,         :null => false
      t.string :email,            :null => false
      t.string :crypted_password, :null => false
      t.string :salt,             :null => false
      t.timestamps
      end
      add_index :authors, :email, unique: true
      end
      end
```

I really want to get this table out of the database and push in a new table.
Thanks a lot for your help ! This is the original problem that made me restart at an earlier level and made me lose so much time.

Comment: You can `rake db:migrate:reset` if you don't care about the data locally. You'll have to `rake db:seed` after, or just put new stuff in since that will delete everything.

Comment: Thanks jeremy for your answer! Will that delete the structure of some models that I perfected through migrations ? Will I have to redo all migrations ?

Comment: the `rake db:migrate:reset` command will just drop the entire database, then re-run all migrations from the very beginning. It is just a quick way to resync all your migrations if they're out like you have. No need to change models or anything (usually).

Comment: It s not letting me run rake db:migrate:reset. It says :

Answer (score 0):

You can do `db:migrate:down VERSION=your_migration_version` to drop the table from the database, then delete the migration file and then run the migrations that `devise` needs for your authentication.

**However**, make sure that you don't need the `authors` table in any migrations until the devise one as it won't exist and can be a potentially big problem with your codebase and everything.

Comment: IS the version the timestamp that precedes the migration name ?

Comment: You can use both the timestap and the whole filename.